# What does "Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server" really do?

Tags: windows, powershell

Investigating double-hop remoting automation options. 
Line 1 below enables CredSSP on the client side. I can see the change in the registry and in gpedit.msc. However, running line 2 below (on the same host) doesn't change anything in the registry or in gpedit.msc. Where else should I be looking for the config change? Does that Powershell call really do anything..?

line 1:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer $domain
```

line 2:

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server
```

registry path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation

gpedit: under Computer Configuration \ Admin Template \ System \ Credentials Delegate

Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials = enabled

Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials With NTLM-only Server Authentication = Not configured

Answer (score 1):

For CredSSP to work you have to enable the client configuration on the local machine (line 1 in your example), and also the server role on the remote machine (line 2).
To see the changes that line 2 causes, you should use the WSMan provider in PowerShell.

Before enabling the server role:

```
PS C:\> dir WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\CredSSP


   WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Service\Auth

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value 
----            ----                           -------------   -----  
System.String   CredSSP                                        false
```

Once the server role is enabled:

```
PS C:\> Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server

cfg               : http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/config/service/auth
lang              : en-US
Basic             : false
Kerberos          : true
Negotiate         : true
Certificate       : false
CredSSP           : true
CbtHardeningLevel : Relaxed

PS C:\> dir WSMan:\localhost\Service\Auth\CredSSP

   WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Service\Auth

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   CredSSP                                        true
```

These settings configure the WinRM service.